# Frameless window but with buttons keeper

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to achieve like this below:

[image]

However, when I use `setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`, It looks like this:

[image]

How to hava a button like this? And also a round corner instead of a straight corner.

Comment: Erm... requirement looks contradicting. What do you currently have? What do you understand under frameless window if it should still have a frame with a close button?

Comment: Hummmm... Maybe with out the title bar but still have the close button.

Comment: I suppose you'll have to resort to your own custom close button (and you won't be able to theme it natively, at least not on X11).

Comment: Found solution by this awesome Qt5 project: Qt-Nice-Frameless-Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Qt-Nice-Frameless-Window` can solve this in macOS.